# Email Notification from Alias email address

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**The Script:**

```
function onFormSubmit() {


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Form responses 4");
var lastresponse =       ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 1, 1, 18).getValues();
var customerEmail = lastresponse[0][10];  
var Subject = "sample updates # " + lastresponse[0][1];
var alias = GmailApp.getAliases();


var Message = "Hello Team" +  ",<br/>"
+ "Please Find Below Details :<br/>"
+ "BN : <b>" + lastresponse[0][1] + "</b><br/>"
+ "PN : <b>" + lastresponse[0][12] + "</b><br/>"
+ "MN : <b>" + lastresponse[0][13] + "</b><br/>"
+ "MN1 : <b>" + lastresponse[0][14] + "</b><br/>"
+ "QP = <b>" + lastresponse[0][3] + "</b><br/>"
+ "QS = <b>" + lastresponse[0][4] + "</b><br/>"
+ "FR = <b>" + lastresponse[0][5] + "</b><br/>"
+ "SLR = <b>" + lastresponse[0][6] + "</b><br/>"
+ "SLRV = <b>" + lastresponse[0][7] + "</b><br/>"
+ "FR = <b>" + lastresponse[0][8] + "</b><br/>"
+ "PR = <b>" + lastresponse[0][9] +"</b><br/>"
+ "Co : <b>" + lastresponse[0][11] + "</b><br/>"

+ "<b>please do not, reply on this    email.<b><br/>"
+ "Thank you";

GmailApp.sendEmail(customerEmail, Subject, Message, { from:alias[0],htmlBody: Message,name: 'Updates'});
 }
```

I set up email notification on google form submit using alias email address but when the whole group receive email notification I am the only one who receive email from alias email address but everyone else receives email notification from my primary email address.

I am sending email notification using workspace account. Email notification set up using Appscript.

Is there anything I am missing to set this up for all?

Comment: Please share the part of the code you are using.

Comment: @RemcoE33 updated post accordingly.

Comment: Try setting the [replyTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options) to the same alias.

Comment: @RemcoE33 not working.  I want that everyone receive email notification from my alias email address, that’s what I am trying to achieve. 
Right now when email notification triggers I receive notification from alias email address but everyone else receives notification from my primary email address.

Comment: Is there a way to authorize script using generic email address?

Comment: #1 Delete the trigger from the current user. #2 Share file with generic. #3Setup the trigger via generic account.

Comment: @RemcoE33 Did the same thing but still wonders then what is the use of noReply:true / Alias functionality when it is not useful.